# Python PIL draw_ellipse or draw_rectangle

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm an old timer, having programmed in Fortran, C, C++, Perl, and a bit
of Java over the years, and trying to learn this new-fangled Python language.

I've got a small program that uses PIL to create an image, draw some
primitives (rectanges, ellipses, etc...) and save it to PNG.  Works fine...
no issues.

I've found in the past, the best way to *"really learn"* a language
was to *"peek under the hood"* and understand the mechanics (pun intended!)... I thought I was making
progress... but when looking into the PIL library to see what was going on
behind the scenes, I found the following code in **ImageDraw.py**

```
def ellipse(self, xy, fill=None, outline=None):
    """Draw an ellipse."""
    ink, fill = self._getink(outline, fill)
    if fill is not None:
        self.draw.draw_ellipse(xy, fill, 1)
    if ink is not None:
        self.draw.draw_ellipse(xy, ink, 0)
```

So, **ellipse()** calls the method  **self.draw.draw_ellipse()**   Okay, fine...
but WHERE is **draw_ellipse(...)** defined??  What magic is happening there?
I've searched the entire PIL directory tree (and even the entire python tree...), and the ONLY two places **draw_ellipse** is mentioned are right there in the **ellipse()** method definition...  I've even tried stepping through it in the debugger and I'm still "buggered" :-) as to what's happening under the hood.

WHAT am I missing??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

draw_ellipse is defined in a _imaging.c file. Please see the followings.

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/_imaging.c

Since the code is written in c (maybe for a Library's performance improvement) and you only have a compiled PIL package, you can not see the original code. The compiled file have a name starting with `_imaging.cpy.~`. In my environment, it's `_imaging.cpython-36m-darwin.so`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, not sure why I didn't think to go grab the source tree, but I won't forget it again!  Thanks for kicking my brain out of its infinite loop!!